# Getting location update after certain distance (5 m in my case)

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, core-location

I am taking input of distance filter from user. For testing purpose I am taking it to be 5 m. But I am getting no location updates after walking 5 m. I am testing it on iPhone simulator 5s.

MainScreenController.m

```
@interface MainScreenController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtTakeDistance;
-(void)writeToTextFile : (NSArray<CLLocation *> *) location;
-(void)ShowContentlist;
@end

@implementation MainScreenController
{
    //CLLocation *location;
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];


}
- (IBAction)btnSetDistance:(id)sender {

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters; // Tried every accuracy option
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = [_txtTakeDistance.text doubleValue];

    if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


}



- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

 NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
 UIAlertController *controller = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to fecth current location" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
 UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

 }];
 [controller addAction:okAction];
 [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
 }


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations{

 CLLocation *currentLoaction;
 currentLoaction = [locations lastObject];

     if(locations != nil){

     NSLog(@"--> : %@",locations);

     [self writeToTextFile:locations];
 }
     [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

 }

-(void)writeToTextFile : (NSArray<CLLocation *> *) location{

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    CLLocation *currentLocation;
    currentLocation = [location lastObject];
    NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timeFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"];

    NSString *timeStamp = [timeFormat stringFromDate:currentLocation.timestamp];
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%f|%f|%@\n",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,currentLocation.coordinate.longitude,timeStamp];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:documentDir]==YES) {

        NSString *documentFile = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"log.txt"];
        NSString *textFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:documentFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        NSString *textToFile = [textFromFile stringByAppendingString:content];
        [textToFile writeToFile:documentFile atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    }else{

        NSLog(@"No such file");
    }
}
```

Do correct me if I am doing it in wrong way. All the suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Selecting an accuracy of nearest 10m and a distance filter of 5m is contradictory.  How are you simulating the movement in your simulator?

Comment: @Paulw11 I have tried accuracy best too. but nothing happened. After running my app I am setting Location to free way (tried all options ) in debug option of simulator and moving my mac to certain distance.

Comment: Moving your Mac won't have any impact on the simulator.

Comment: @Paulw11 oh okay, thanks for sharing this. Is there any way to check it on simulator ?

Comment: Yes, Freeway drive should work

Comment: @Paulw11 but it is not. Any suggestion why ?

Comment: Do you get the prompt to allow access to location?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes , first time when I started my app I got that. Infact I am getting location for the first time but getting nothing after moving.

Comment: You have a call to `stopUpdatingLocation` at the end of `didUpdateLocations` - so you only get a single update.  Once I removed that your code works

Comment: You shouldn't call it anywhere unless you want to stop receiving location updates

Comment: @Paulw11  If I remove that I get frequent updates without moving.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113410/discussion-between-paulw11-and-sharad-chauhan).

Answer (score 0):

Make some change in your code like:

```
- (IBAction)btnSetDistance:(id)sender {

locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;

locationManager.distanceFilter =5;

if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

and most important thing is,you can not check how much distance you moved by moving mac.

you should check it on your device.

Comment: if you are just changing the accuracy then I must tell you that I have tried every options including yours.

Comment: Okay thanks. I will go for device if I have nothing left to work on simulator.

Comment: okay..coz your code is correct..nothing wrong in that.. just check all things e.g.--- Enable Background Modes from Capabilities Tab, and choose Location Updates...

Comment: Done everything. I think I should go for device then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
- (IBAction)btnSetDistance:(id)sender
{
    locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate=self;
    if (([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]))
    {
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 5;   // change it according to need
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}
```

with this line `locationManager.distanceFilter = 5;` every 5 meter distance if you cover map will update

To get the updated Latitude and Longitudes use this code

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
    NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

    double  lat = location.coordinate.latitude;
    double  longi = location.coordinate.longitude;

    if (abs(howRecent) < 15.0)

    {
        NSLog(@"%f,%f",lat,longi);
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
```