# Location Manger is not updating location on ios 16+

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I am using this code snippet which enables location tracking

```
    - (void)enableOrDisableLocationTracking {
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger trackingSetting = [userDefaults integerForKey:@"trackingSetting"];
    
    if (trackingSetting == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Location tracking is enabled");
        
        self.locationTracker = [[CustomLocationTracker alloc] init];
        self.locationTracker.delegate = self;
        
        [self.locationTracker.normalLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        
        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSInteger gpsSetting = [userDefaults integerForKey:@"gpsSetting"];
        
        if (self.sharedModel.isFollowMeActive) {
            if (gpsSetting > 3) {
                [self.locationTracker updateGPSSensitivity:gpsSetting];
                [self.locationTracker updateSignificantGPSSensitivity:gpsSetting];
            } else {
                [self.locationTracker updateGPSSensitivity:3];
                [self.locationTracker updateSignificantGPSSensitivity:3];
            }
        } else {
            [self.locationTracker updateGPSSensitivity:gpsSetting];
            [self.locationTracker updateSignificantGPSSensitivity:gpsSetting];
        }
        
        [self.locationTracker.normalLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        
        // Significant location changes
        [self.locationTracker.significantLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        [self.locationTracker.significantLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
        
        switch (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus) {
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied: {
                NSLog(@"User denied location access request");
                [self.locationTracker.normalLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
                
                UIAlertController *alertVC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Limited Functionality" message:@"GPS Denied. Go to Settings and set Allow Location Access to Always" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                UIAlertAction* okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
                }];
                [alertVC addAction:okAction];
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:alertVC animated:YES completion:nil];
                
            } break;
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse: {
                NSLog(@"Show panel to ask for full authorization");
                [self.locationTracker.normalLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
                UIAlertController *alertVC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Limited Functionality" message:@"GPS Limited. Go to Settings and set Allow Location Access to Always" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                UIAlertAction* okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
                }];
                [alertVC addAction:okAction];
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:alertVC animated:YES completion:nil];
            } break;
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways: {
                NSLog(@"User granted full permission, good to go");
            } break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Location tracking is disabled");
        
        if (self.locationTracker != nil) {
            [self.locationTracker.normalLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
            [self.locationTracker.significantLocationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
            self.locationTracker.delegate = nil;
            self.locationTracker = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

On the simulator, I do this and I do receive location updates

[image]

but on a ***real device***, it doesn't give any updates instead   this method is called

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {}
```

and gives this error

***Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"***

I see lots of other solutions but non of them worked for me

Comment: zero means location unknown. Have you tried Freeway drive?

Comment: yes i just tried same issue

Comment: did you add Privacy - Location Always Usage Description or Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description include  ??

Comment: please check this also

locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;

locationManager.distanceFilter =5;

Comment: @chanadboy Yes i have all these setups already 
 significantLocationManager.distanceFilter = 2;
            significantLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these points.

1. check permission in plist file
2. locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
   locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;

   locationManager.distanceFilter = 5; ( you can change it)

for reference link

[Getting location update after certain distance (5 m in my case)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37544514/getting-location-update-after-certain-distance-5-m-in-my-case)

[How to work with user location in iOS 16 App Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74588726/how-to-work-with-user-location-in-ios-16-app-intents)

[image]

Comment: i do have all the permissions
and accuracy setup but location updates are not happening it just throw this
Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" and does nothing